# After finding an edge and its destination by go, how to show up the information of destination in NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

Nebula Graph Database  version: 3.2

-Problem

After I find the destination of this edge by `go` from `somevertex` over `someedge` yield `dst`(edge), how to display the information of this destination instead of the VertexID.

Answer (score 0):

You could yield things like:

- properties($$)
- properties($$).PropBar

Where $$ refers to the dest. of the go traversal(note: no matter in which direction)

Check out the docs, you’ll find go examples cover this and reference expressions like $$.